# Trouble understanding the 2nd form of Foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

Hello i understand  the first form of foreach

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
```

But after reading through the documentation i quite still dont understand the form:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

is the key -> value have to do something with hash tables. So when u do a foreach on a hash table u have to do this to get the value?

If possible a small example would be terrific/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an array with 2 elements. The keys are "red" and "yellow" . The values are "apple" and "car" .

Try this to understand the second way to use foreach

```
<?php   
$samples = array("red" => "apple" , "yellow" => "car");
foreach($samples as $key => $sample)
   echo $key . " - " . $sample . "<br>";
?>
```

The Result

```
red - apple
yellow - car
```

The word which is `"as"` in the foreach loop used to convert `array("a"=>"b")` to `$key=>$value` for every sequence of loop.

**In the other word, key "a" drop into $key variable and value "b" drop
into $value variable.**

Comment: k seems straight foward enough , what happens when u call this without there being an associative array

Comment: For example , array("a","b") which is an associative array .. In this example keys are 0 and 1 . Values are "a" and "b" .. So if the array were be the others the result would be 
0 - a <br />
1 - b

Answer (score 0):

With the second for you can access the actual element's key in your loop.

I think the manual is really detailed:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php